# Which keyboard characters can be read with getchar() on Linux

Tags: getchar

I have a C++ application running on Ubuntu that waits for a key press using getchar() function. The input is not used, I just end my program with any keypress.

I noticed I could type basically any [printable](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html) character, but also some [unprintable](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html) characters such as the <kbd>escape</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> keys. Keys that did not trigger the ending of my program were keys such as <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

So my question is, which key presses get read by getchar()? How can I classify those, since apparantly not only printable characters trigger getchar()?

I could not find the answer in the man page or the C++ reference.

This is basically all the code I wrote:

```
std::cout << "Ready for input ..." << std::endl;
std::getchar();
std::cout << "A key was pressed, landing ..." << std::endl;
```

Mind that I do manipulate termios to not wait for a newline character and to not echo.

Comment: Is it not all characters? in windows, it is working for almost keys. did u write any code?

Comment: Try to use curses library if you want an easy way to handle it

Comment: I added a code sample @MasOOd.KamYab.

Comment: I did not ask how I could handle it @Ôrel, just how getchar() works.

Comment: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/getchar.c.html `getchar()` uses a _buffered_ input, you can read the raw input if you really need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the keys that getchar() does not catch are [Modifier](https://techterms.com/definition/modifierkey) keys. Maybe just because they are simply "modifiers" and always are used together with another key to create a specific charater. If anyone knows the particular reason, I would like to know.

Comment: That's a bit too simple. Is '\`' a modifier key? On my keyboard, the answer varies depending on the language I'm using. When I'm writing code or English, the answer is no. When I use languages that have the letter à, I use ` as a modifier.

Comment: @MSalters In the references I saw, modifier keys are defined as not triggering an action by themselves, just entering a sort of [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(computer_interface)#Quasimodes). So I do not think '`' is a modifier key, you kinda proved it by typing it? Wikipedia calls those [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) apparently, since you have to press and release them before they modify the next character typed.

Comment: I type ` by typing a space afterwards. So yes, that's two keys for one character.

Comment: So again that is a "dead key" then, and not a "modifier key" since you need to press and release them before they alter te next character instead of just the press.

Answer (score -1):

`getchar` reads from `stdin`, not directly from the keyboard. The bit that you're missing is hinted at by your assumption of "keyboard characters". That's missing the translation from *key presses* to characters. For instance, the key presses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> produces `A`. How you enter `à` depends on the xact keyboard configuration.

Comment: I see the difference now, though this does not answer my question. See my answer below.